# Folders are hidden inside external hard disk

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have a 500 GB external hard disk, I think it's due to virus, all of the folders are hidden with read only attribute.

I tried this command in Command Prompt under Administrative privilages:

```
attrib -h -r -s /s /d i:\*.*
```

But it throws me "Access Denied" error. I tried with disabling Folder Options -> Protect Operating system files, now I am able to see the files but I am not able to change the hidden attribute (as Hidden checkbox is disabled). Can anyone please help? I am using Windows 7. I tried with virus scan, strangely it doesn't report any virus.

Comment: Check the permission of the ext HDD (or the folder) and make sure you have ownership. If you right click on the HDD, Properties - Security, you can see if you have ownership or not.

Comment: @Darius, yes. I have permission.

Comment: Permission to the HDD (top level) or just on the folders? Also, when you run attrib, did you run it from Command Prompt that is "Run as Administrator" ?

Comment: @Darius, yes I have permission to HDD top level, I ran attrib from command prompt with "Run as Administrator".

Comment: This is a bit of a workaround (not an answer to your query) but since you said you can see the files, can you copy your files out of the HDD? If yes, then you can then re-format the HDD, copy your data back in, and all should be good.